# How to Make Array of multiple products under category having two arrays using array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have to try to make that type of array but not to make expected array. I have two arrays one is category and one is product array .and i want to combine two arrays,  I have need to display all products under specific category.
Category and product arrays below:

```
$categories = [ 2490 => "POS",2485 => "Online Trainings",2484 => "Onsite Trainings"];
       $product = [
2490=> [ 
    "data"=>[
      0 =>  [
         "prd_id" => "7222",
         "prd_price" => "$21",
         "product_data" => [
              0=>[
                 "prd_sku" => 12,
                 "prd_name" => "Export Ready Program" 
                ]
             ]
      ],
      1=>[
         "prd_id" => "7221",
         "prd_price" => "$25",
         "product_data"=>[
              0=>[
               "prd_sku" => 123 ,      
               "prd_name" => "Workplace Assured",

               ]
             ]
      ]
    ]
 ],
 2485=>[
   "data"=>[
       0=>[
        "prd_id" => "7224",
        "prd_price" => "$45",
        "product_data"=>[
            0=>[
               "prd_sku" => 123 ,  
               "prd_name" => "Exporting Documentation"
              ]
            ]
       ]
    ]
 ],
  2484 =>[
     "data"=>[ 0=>[
        "prd_id" => "7223",
        "prd_price" => "$15",
        "product_data"=>[
            0=>[
                "prd_sku" => 124 ,  
               "prd_name" => "clock"
              ]
            ]
      ]
    ]
]
];
```

**My code :**

```
$finalArray = [];
foreach($product AS $key=>$data){
    $firstArray = [];
    $firstArray['category_id'] = $key;
    $firstArray['category_name'] = $categories[$key];
    $i = 1;
    foreach($data AS $k=>$datum){
        $firstArray['product_category_listng'][$i]['product_id'] = $datum['prd_id'];
        $firstArray['product_category_listng'][$i]['product_name'] = $datum['prd_name'];
        $finalArray = $firstArray;
        $i++;
    }
}
print_r($finalArray);
```

**My expected Output should be:**

```
   Array
(
    [2490] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 2490
            [category_name] => POS
            [product_category_listing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [prd_id] => 7222
                            [prd_name] => Export Ready Program
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [prd_id] => 7221
                            [prd_name] => Workplace Assured
                        )
                )
        )

    [2485] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 2485
            [category_name] => Online Trainings
            [product_category_listing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [prd_id] => 7224
                            [prd_name] => Exporting Documentation
                        )
                )
        )

    [2484] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 2484
            [category_name] => Onsite Trainings
            [product_category_listing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [prd_id] => 7223
                            [prd_name] => clock
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Please help 
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Okay, and what's going wrong with your current code?

Comment: You cannot get expected output because you can't have duplicate keys like `category_id`, `category_name` etc...

Comment: @Patrick Q it's print only single array not multiple array

Comment: Your expected output cannot work because it contains duplicate keys. Other than that a bit of array_map() and array_replace() should do the trick.

Comment: @Dormilich which duplicates keys?

Comment: @RaheelAslam each key in the 'expected output' occurs multiple times.

Comment: @Dormilich each keys and category name is unique 2490,2485,2484 these are categories under this one or more products may be.

Comment: Right, but the _keys_ need to be unique.  You can't have the same key multiple times in an array.  How would you differentiate between them when accessing?  What you really want is to have each category as a sub-array within your outer array, and _then_ have your current structure within that.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86ddd8689d8f3aa31f32f17c77982758bd69c3e9

Comment: check code it's return only single result of array

Comment: Because array keys must be unique. This is what we're telling you the whole time!

Comment: From these array what will be output array, can you change my output structure

Comment: What will be my output structure array can you change?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have change product array and output array can you  design your code according to output

Comment: @PatrickQ can you see changing of question and update according to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than what you are doing in your code.  You can use `category_id` as the index:

```
foreach($product as $category => $values) {
    $result[$category]['category_id'] = $category;
    $result[$category]['category_name'] = $categories[$category];
    $result[$category]['product_category_listing'] = $values;
}
```

Or dynamically assign indexes:

```
foreach($product as $category => $values) {
    $result[] = ['category_id' => $category,
                 'category_name' => $categories[$category],
                 'product_category_listing' => $values];
}
```

The first example yields (the second example indexes will be 0, 1, 2):

```
Array
(
    [2490] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 2490
            [category_name] => POS
            [product_category_listing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [prd_id] => 7222
                            [prd_name] => Export Ready Program
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [prd_id] => 7221
                            [prd_name] => Workplace Assured
                        )
                )
        )

    [2485] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 2485
            [category_name] => Online Trainings
            [product_category_listing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [prd_id] => 7224
                            [prd_name] => Exporting Documentation
                        )
                )
        )

    [2484] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 2484
            [category_name] => Onsite Trainings
            [product_category_listing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [prd_id] => 7223
                            [prd_name] => clock
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: let me check it with different scenarios

Comment: i am using in my own code $i++ is best approach or not ?

Comment: can you explain that?

Comment: Why?  `[]` does the same thing.  If I thought `$i++` was the best then it would be in my code. And the array in `product_category_listing` already is an array with those indexes.

Comment: thanks for reply because some people use with empty array [] like ["category"][].

Comment: You don't have to loop through each `product` because it is already an array and you can just use it.

Comment: can you change the output according to my question please.

Comment: please review the question

Comment: have you seen the changing?